# How do you write a .txt file`s contents into syslog on a Mac?

Tags: macos, bash

I have a .txt file that stores specific query information about Macs, I want this information to be copied or written to the syslog file as well. Essentially I want the contents of the file to be written to the syslog. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `logger` (from `man logger`):

> `-f`, `--file file`
>
> ```
>       Log  the contents of the specified file.
>       This option cannot be combined with command-line message.
> ```

E.g.:

```
$ logger -p local0.notice -t MYPROGRAM -f /tmp/myprogram.log
```